# What is a good tool for quantifying inheritance in a code base?

Tags: java, inheritance

Does anybody know of any tool which can analyze a code base and advise if there is too much inheritance? In an objective manner.  Something that could look at 500 classes, and calculate that X classes have a depth Y? That kind of thing.  Thanks. Something that is more design-focused rather than code-focused.

Comment: How much inheritance is too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sonar tool](http://www.sonarsource.org/) can help you.

Check the page from [Andrew Spencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587365/andrew-spencer) in the comments, look for Depth of inheritance tree.

Many thanks to you, Andrew !

Comment: Sonar is a great tool but I'm not sure it has that exact metric (though I admit I'm not using the latest version).

Comment: Oh yes, it does: look for "dit" in [this page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions)

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Nice ! I was looking through their site if it actually has this metric, you were better than me at looking for it :)

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Depth of inheritance tree, that's it ! Well done Andrew, I'm editing my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

JavaDepend [checks this](http://www.javadepend.com/Metrics.aspx#DIT) and other code matrices